# Is it possible to devise a subtraction algorithm that does not first compare the inputs?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, subtraction

Obviously, any competent programming language has built-in subtraction. However, say you needed to implement a custom subtraction algorithm (say, to handle very large numbers). If you are using the borrowing method, you would have to first compare the inputs to determine if the result will be negative, and if so, you switch the order of the subtraction. I am curious if it is possible to write an algorithm that does not need this comparison/operand swapping?

Further, could such an algorithm be more efficient than compare-first, which in the worst case would have to compare every place value?

*I am aware that one could use complements, but this limits the size of permitted inputs (assuming finite representation size).

Answer (score 1):

If you are implementing bignums, then you can combine the comparison and the subtraction so that you only look at each ["limb"](https://gmplib.org/manual/Nomenclature-and-Types.html#index-Limb) once, except for one. (The word "limb" comes from the Gnu MP library but it is also used elsewhere to mean the same thing.)

First, you scan from the big end of the longer number until you find a nonzero limb or you reach thr length of the smaller number. In the first case, you know that the longer number is bigger and you also know the position of its most significant limb. (If you have adopted the convention that numbers always have a nonzero most-significant limb then you can skip this step.)

Suppose now that you didn't prove the the longer number is bigger, so you know are at the same position in both numbers. Continue scanning both numbers until you find a difference. At this point, you know which number is bigger and you also know the position of the most significant limb of the larger number.

So now you know which number is bigger, and you can do the normal borrowing algorithm from the low-order ends of the numbers, stopping when you reach the high-order limb which you previously identified.

Since the two scans stop at the same place, you don't look at any limb more than once, exvept the high-order limb which stopped the first scan.

---

Whether it is actually worthwhile to implement this hack is something you would have to decide. The complication may not be justfiable. But it is *possible*.

Comment: That's how LargeInteger subtraction is implemented in Squeak Smalltalk. It does not add much complexity.